# JNLP Application - Lib folder not being sent to client

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a java webstart application that I have converted from an Applet to an Application since applets are deprecated. In my attempt at modifying the html file that points to the jnlp file, I seem to be unable to get the program to launch. When I hit the link, the jnlp file downloads but not the corresponding lib folder. Any ideas on why?

I am able to run the application in eclipse as an application fine. So the issues are related to the JNLP. The jars are also properly signed.

The error I get when the .jnlp is kicked off is that it is unable to find /lib/MyJar.jar. It attempts to launch java and I get that runtime exception. I get the same exception (though looking for the jar in different locations) from both Chrome (treats it as a download) and IE (puts it in temp folders).

Launch HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Application</h3>
        <br>
        <a href="/param.xml" download="param.xml">Download param.xml file</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="/launch.jnlp">Launch Application</a>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

JNLP File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="launch.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Application</title>
        <vendor>Info</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>Application description</description>
            </information>
        <security>
     <all-permissions/>
  </security>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>              

    <jar href="lib/Application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/dd-plist-1.19.jar"/>

    </resources>
    <applet-desc main-class="My.Main.Class" name="Application"
        width="1000" height="500">
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Are you able to run the JNLP file. Running the .jnlp file is what caches the JAR. Your browser or OS may not understand how to run a .jnlp.

Comment: Meaning can I open the JNLP once it is on my machine? Yes. If I double click it, you see the Java splash screen pop up before the Exception that it can't find my jars.

Comment: I think you just needed to set codebase + href atributes to the full server URL path.

Comment: *"I have a java webstart application that I have converted from an Applet to an Application since applets are deprecated."* So is Java Web Start.

Comment: Really? What has replaced it?

Comment: No direct replacement. Depends on what your application is doing: Client/Server Application or Standalone App, jlink,....there are lots of possibilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by switching:

```
    <a href="/launch.jnlp">Launch Application</a>
```

to

```
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
        <a href="javascript:deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('launch.jnlp');">Launch Application</a>
```